# Using Rx to limit to X concurrent Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I'm very new to Rx, and I'm trying to use it to have up to X number of concurrent subscribing tasks. The data source is actually from a database, so I'm having to poll the database. I realise that the idea behind Rx is that it's *push* and not *pull* - so the poll doesn't really fit that well, but conceptually the data going into the database is a stream of events that I want to subscribe to and do something with.

The main issue that I have is that the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` doesn't seem to be successfully limiting to the specified number of tasks. It runs a lot more concurrently than the 8 I've specified.

I'm also unsure which is the better way out of the two below solutions (or possibly, both are wrong?!).

Here's one method I've tried which uses the `Observable.Timer` ...

```
public static void Main()
{
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory (new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler (8));
    var scheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler (taskFactory);

    Observable.Timer (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (10), scheduler)
        .SelectMany (x => Observable.FromAsync (GetItemsSource))
        .Repeat ()
        .ObserveOn (scheduler)
        .Subscribe (x => Observable.FromAsync(y => DoSomethingAsync (x.ToList())));

    Console.ReadKey ();
}

private static async Task<IEnumerable<Guid>> GetItemsSource()
{
    return await _myRepo.GetMoreAsync(10);
}

private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> items)
{
    // Do something with the data
}
```

I've also tried doing it this way instead ...

```
public static void Main()
{
    GetItemsSource()
        .ObserveOn(scheduler)
        .Select (async x => await DoSomethingAsync(x))
        .Subscribe();

    Console.ReadKey ();
}

public static IObservable<Guid> GetItemsSource()
{
    return Observable.Create<Guid>(
        async obs =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var item = (await _myRepo.GetMoreAsync(1)).FirstOrDefault();

                if(item != null)
                {
                    obs.OnNext(item);
                }

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
            }
        });
}

private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> items)
{
    // Do something with the data
}
```

Obviously very simple examples, without error handling or cancellation support.

Both seem to work, but neither limit to 8 concurrent tasks.

As I say, I'm very new to Rx, and am probably missing lots of fundamental things. I certainly plan on doing a lot of reading to fully understand Rx as it seems very powerful, but for now I want to get something working quickly.

#### UPDATE

Following on from Enigmativity's answer and comments, here's some code which logs out the concurrent counts ...

```
void Main()
{
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(8));
    var scheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(taskFactory);

    using (
        (
            from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), scheduler)
            from g in Observable.FromAsync(GetItemsSource, scheduler)
            from u in Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomethingAsync(g), scheduler)
            select u)
        .ObserveOn(scheduler)
        .Subscribe())
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private static volatile int _numIn = 0;
private static volatile int _numOut = 0;

public static async Task<IEnumerable<Guid>> GetItemsSource()
{
    try
    {
        _numIn++;

        $"Concurrent tasks (in): {_numIn}".Dump();

        // Simulate async API call
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

        return new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid() };
    }
    finally
    {
        _numIn--;
    }
}

private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> deliveryIds)
{
    try
    {
        _numOut++;

        // Simulate async calls required to process the event
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        $"Concurrent tasks (out): {_numOut}".Dump();
    }
    finally
    {
        _numOut--;
    }
}
```

This shows around 64 concurrent tasks running.

#### Update 2

It does look like this is because the subscriber is async. If I test using a non-async subscriber, it works fine. Unfortunately I need to have an async subscriber, as it needs to call other async methods.

It looks like I can do something similar by doing this ...

```
GetItemsSource2()
    .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomethingAsync(x)))
    .Merge(64)
    .Subscribe();
```

So using `Merge` instead of the `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`.

Comment: How do you know that it isn't limited to 8 concurrent tasks? And how many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: You're really mixing Rx, TPL and Linq-for-objects here. You shouldn't do that. Most of everything here can be does with Rx. Stay pure. It's much easier.

Comment: I don't think your update is showing how many tasks are running - it's showing how many tasks ran during the time from the call to `GetItemsSource` and to `DoSomethingAsync`. It's like having a road that can only fit 8 cars across, but you're counting the front cars and the 7 immediately behind them.

Comment: I don't really understand. `_numOut` is only used in the `DoSomethingAsync` method. It's incremented when it starts, and decremented when it ends. Surely that indicated how many of them are running concurrently?

Comment: Looks like it's related to the async subscriber. I've got around it by using `Merge` instead (see my *Update 2*. Thanks for your help @Enigmativity! :)

Answer (score 1):

I got your code to work by doing this:

```
void Main()
{
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(8));
    var scheduler = new TaskPoolScheduler(taskFactory);

    using (Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), scheduler)
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.FromAsync(GetItemsSource))
        .Repeat()
        .ObserveOn(scheduler)
        .Subscribe(async x => await DoSomethingAsync(x.ToList())))
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    };
}

private static async Task<IEnumerable<Guid>> GetItemsSource()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray());
}

private static async Task DoSomethingAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> items)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(String.Join("|", items.Select(x => x.ToString()))));
}
```

I also modified the `QueueTask` method of `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` to include a trace line for the numbers of running delegates:

```
protected sealed override void QueueTask(Task task)
{
    // Add the task to the list of tasks to be processed.  If there aren't enough 
    // delegates currently queued or running to process tasks, schedule another. 
    lock (_tasks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_delegatesQueuedOrRunning);
        _tasks.AddLast(task);
        if (_delegatesQueuedOrRunning < _maxDegreeOfParallelism)
        {
            ++_delegatesQueuedOrRunning;
            NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork();
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran your code I got this output:

```
0
1
1
1
874695ca-e9a8-4688-a4d2-d7d2446e7924|e3cbadf1-c5cb-4339-ab59-33d873db98f2|8dd710f5-0b21-4b20-a547-6ccfe7c29af4|42739c5a-4602-4f76-8aed-40f1c0ffccdc|c599e879-06ca-459f-b27e-95ac15dc4cc1|562b5f7c-dcb2-47d8-aa4a-503499654139|b78e5fc5-d152-4380-9799-2713c6f71c19|e47669a3-a399-4891-91b6-3a28b52a941a|f6483f2f-f8d7-47e8-9f88-bf9bc5f61f3a|c8e75203-bc55-4e00-9f8b-ecf248f81454
2
2
1
2
3
92d6f76e-6a3d-475d-8c1c-bd3e59aaf2a1|1b2bd0d6-c439-4b3c-a1f1-9af1f5132afc|c140e0ec-6741-4310-9edf-547fdf390b01|5b29dcd3-21c9-46a2-ae98-cd7a7b1a003c|5a808def-a09f-41a7-acfc-d11cfbbb4faa|28f47d0c-7762-4949-ae33-427c82756874|13087b1c-c4eb-4f0f-bf5f-665a2298ac13|50c00907-668d-44f3-9e2a-c790348fb715|34f8602a-18ef-45b6-b069-0fb30718a45b|46d6616d-0e89-49cd-8905-dff72bb63add
2
1
1
2
7c6cbe5a-43d1-4aad-8eee-33a0d7f44276|2164e3e0-4e8d-4a57-99b7-0aa5e42281da|e2cf26ed-501f-4032-9761-53a301e16bb9|a3e9171a-f490-4135-a930-017dc706293e|b9f43f5c-d652-4205-b857-724699f178c5|5d8e6149-f9ad-424d-9ee2-07afa344ab80|418d2526-adf6-4c26-ac84-636400fce547|3b8c3b14-9e91-4bb8-9cfa-c1d36f12ccc0|be3c8c84-5112-4c85-ba7f-d1b41a2ec03a|bdc34ccb-a3d9-45fa-bf54-d42bcd791081
2
1
1
2
3d5e0d0a-ddb3-4595-b960-4d2050d4fa1a|1b5a39c9-652c-4872-8d1c-6e1212cd4043|fd9aff7b-9c77-47e4-a4c6-2ede38472b92|ff6145d3-2dc2-45b6-bc40-2cc1f270572d|5ba0e441-a9f1-4b2a-baca-127cce622993|e2650bb9-f2e4-4a89-8c2c-69859f5f381a|a86a1f4e-7ea7-465c-9730-7ac735c5616e|5cf7135b-fafe-4725-938e-5e7ea55f4c3e|dd26bda7-d86b-4bb9-977f-a29ef5cf6d76|6e77c1c1-4e8d-4b48-b6f4-d54f0ec9d269
1
1
```

...etc...

Your code never hits more than 3 concurrent tasks.

Now I'd suggest that you try to write your code in a more Rx-ish kind of way. Try this:

```
using (
(
    from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), scheduler)
    from g in Observable.FromAsync(() => GetItemsSource(), scheduler)
    from u in Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomethingAsync(g), scheduler)
    select u)
    .ObserveOn(scheduler)
    .Subscribe())
{
    Console.ReadLine();
};
```

It doesn't change the number of tasks used, but it's cleaner.

Comment: There must be something else I'm doing wrong then - as your latter example is also using far more than 8. I'm monitoring it by just having a refcount in the various methods. My DoSomethingAsync calls an API endpoint, so I'm also monitoring the number of concurrent requests on that end too - which also shows way more than 8. I'll try your first example now. I just know it'll be something really obvious and stupid I'm doing! :)

Comment: @Dan - I think there's a measuring issue. I've shown that there are no more than 3 concurrent tasks. How are you seeing more? Please post your code that shows it so that I can run it myself.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with some code that shows the issue. Thank you for your help btw - it's greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How did you modify `QueueTask`? Was it just your own implementation of `TaskScheduler`? Looking at `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler`, its `QueueTask` is sealed.

Comment: Never mind - I can see the source to `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` is online, so I've done the same. And the `_delegatesQueuedOrRunning` is much lower than my `_numOut`. I don't really understand why though - unless my `DoSomethingAsync` is never being awaited on, so it doesn't know how many are running?

Comment: I think my "cars on an 8 lane road" analogy applies here. Keep in mind that any tasks created by `DoSomethingAsync` are not using your custom scheduler.